# Replacing an Error message in a Calculator with a new integer, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, error-handling, calculator

I am building a very simple calculator using vanilla JS. The only part missing is whenever there is an error message given, I would like to replace it with a new integer instead of having to press clear. For example:

- I type an invalid input like "6/*" and press "="
- The calculator screen shows "Error",
- Pressing "5" or any other integer would wipe the Error message and replace it with the integer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're asking to replace the error with a number when an integer is clicked

Right now you have:

```
if (operators.includes(self.value) || operands.includes(self.value)) {
    document.calculator.equation.value += self.value;
}
```

So that would mean that when you press 5 it'll say "Error5"
Try

```
if (operators.includes(self.value) || operands.includes(self.value)) {
    if (document.calculator.equation.value == "Error") {
    document.calculator.equation.value = self.value;
    } else {
    document.calculator.equation.value += self.value;
    }
}
```

That way when you press a button it will check to make sure your value isn't Error before it tries to add a value, and if it is error then it will just replace it